# Cherrypy configuration for cherrypy.quickstart

Tags: python-2.7, cherrypy

This is configuration for /projects endpoint. What modification do i have to add for adding an endpoint   "/projects/all"    at the same port.

```
conf = {
    'global':{
        'server.socket_host': "127.0.0.1",
        'server.socket_port': config.SERVER_PORT
    },
    '/projects': {
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        'tools.response_headers.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'application/json')],
    }
}
webapp = ApiApp()
webapp.projects = ProjectsApi()
cherrypy.quickstart(webapp, '/', conf)
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What do you want to serve at '/projects/all'?

Comment: thanks..but it's been resolved..had to add new endpoint in the conf fictionary..